# How to find out which app is sounding a bell, and how to silence it?

Tags: macos, mojave, notifications

When I put on my headphone I can hear an app keep making a sound (a short bell, perhaps. It's hard to describe in writing) very frequently, almost like once or twice every second.

I have been going thru all app in 'Notifications' in System Preference and uncheck 'Play sound for notifications', for example:

[image]

but it does not seem to stop it.

The only way to completely silence it is by turning on 'Do not disturb' in notification centre.

[image]

By my observation it seems to be closely correlated to Mail's downloading messages activities

[image]

So where can I completely turn off the sound?

Comment: Check System Preferences > Clock and see if you have it set to make a sound on the hour or otherwise. That happened to me a while back  and somehow I had turned that on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the sounds came from the Mail app. It is the 'New messages sound'

[image]

By switching it to `None` I can get rid of the frequent bell sounds.